# Magento2: error cron log

Tags: magento2, cron

I have found any issue in magento.cron.log

```
Warning: proc_open(): fork failed - Resource temporarily unavailable in /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 959#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'proc_open(): fo...', '/home/czasowe/d...', 959, Array)
#1 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(959): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, Array)
#2 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(761): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getSttyColumns()
#3 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(722): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalDimensions()
#4 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(656): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalWidth()
#5 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(127): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->renderException(Object(Exception), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput))
#6 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#7 {main}

Warning: proc_open(): fork failed - Resource temporarily unavailable in /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 959#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'proc_open(): fo...', '/home/czasowe/d...', 959, Array)
#1 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(959): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, Array)
#2 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(761): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getSttyColumns()
#3 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(722): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalDimensions()
#4 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(656): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalWidth()
#5 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(127): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->renderException(Object(Exception), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput))
#6 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#7 {main}
```

Does anyone know what a issue is and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this type of error is because you haven't enough memory.

Magento 2 require 2GB of RAM as mentionned [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

You can try to edit your php.ini to set the memory limit to 2048MB.